# Show modal after redirection, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to show a modal after redirection.

I have seen all the ways on the net but nothing worked.

**Controller**

```
return redirect()->back()->with('code');
```

**Blade**

```
@if(session('code')) )
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#verify_code').modal('show');
  });
</script>
@endif



<div id="verify_code" class="modal custom-modal fade"  role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Verify Phone Number</h3>
      </div><!-- end modal-header -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url('verify_code') }}">
          @csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="code" name="code"  placeholder="Enter verification code" required/>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-orange btn-block">Verify Phone Number</button>
        </form>
      </div><!-- end modal-bpdy -->
    </div><!-- end modal-content -->
  </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- end edit-profile -->
```

Comment: Are you sure session('code') even contains what you think it does?

Try putting on top: {{ dd(session('code')) }} and see if it outputs anything.

Comment: @JCode it comes null :/ ... what should i do ?

Comment: Well, set it ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

The `with` function on redirect can have two parameters, a key and a value. You are passing just a key, `'code'` and by default Laravel will [set the value to `null`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html#method_with).

So, when you fetch the value of `session('code')`, this will return `null`. And php views `null` as a false value, so your condition is never true.

To fix this, pass a value to your `with` function:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('code', true);
```

Comment: I passed the value now, but should I change smth in blade ? Because nothing showed up again.

Comment: Does the javascript function render? And do you get any output in your developer tools?

Comment: Nope I don't get any output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `code` variable is probably never set when it arrives in your view.

If your variable is defined in your code before you try to return it. You can use compact() function to pass it to your view. Like so:

```
return redirect()->back()->with(compact('code'));
```

Compact creates an array containing variables and their values.

Or with just an array:

```
return redirect()->back()->with([
   'code' => $code
]);
```

Once your variable is passed to your view, you can just test it. Assuming `$code` contains a boolean or something not empty:

```
@if ($code)
...
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

i think better approachment like this,

In Controller

```
Session::flash('code','randomvalue');
return redirect()->back();
```

and then change your blade like this

```
//checking if the session has 'code'
@if(Session::has('code'))
your script
@endif
```